# Getting scoping working with Kentor/Sustainsys AuthServices SAML2

Tags: saml-2.0, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2

Has anyone got scoping working with `Kentor/Sustainsys` AuthServices?

The release history https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/releases states that version v0.18.0 has support for scoping and indeed there does seem to be be some scoping classes however they seem to not be used.

Specifically the creation of `Saml2AuthenticationRequest` instances don't include scoping anywhere.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to achieve this through configuration in the web.config or is the code not ready for scoping yet?

I'm trying to use the AuthServices MVC package to add `SAML2` to an existing `MVC` project to support `SSO` as an `SP`.

Answer (score 1):

Override the AuthnRequestCreated notification and modify the AuthnRequest from code.